# Unit test MyBatis with HSQL instead of Oracle

Tags: oracle, hsqldb, mybatis

I would like to unit test my MyBatis persistence layer using an HSQL in-memory database. The real application uses an Oracle database. This worked fine unitl we started adding auto incremented numbers for the id columns. Oracle requires the use of a sequence to get the incremented number so a sequence called basis_seq was created in the Oracle database. In my MyBatis mapper XML file I have this:

```
<insert id="insertBasis" parameterType="com.foo.Basis" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
        <selectKey resultType="long" keyProperty="id" order="BEFORE">
            SELECT basis_seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
        </selectKey>
        insert into basis
        (id, name)
        values
        (#{id}, #{name})
</insert>
```

This works when I run the application but the unit test gets an error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Error selecting key
>   or setting result to parameter object. Cause:
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not
>   found: DUAL ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not
>   found: DUAL

As I understand 'DUAL' is some kind of virtual table in Oracle that stores the sequences and I don't have this in my test database. If I remove the `<selectKey>`-tag the unit test work (since HSQL can autogenerate ids for columns marked `identity`) but not the real application. One workaround would be to create separate MyBatis mapper XML files for the unit tests without the `<selectKey>`-tag but this is undesired since I want to test the real configuration.

Is there a way to create and use a sequence in HSQL as well or maybe some MyBatis workaround for this? Or should I use another database for my unit test like H2?

---

I use:

- Spring 3.0.5
- HSQL 2.2.4
- MyBatis 3.0.5

---

## UPDATE:

After getting the answer from **fredt**, here is how I edited my Spring configuration:

Before I defined my data source with:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data/schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data/data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Now I do this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_ora=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data/schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data/data.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Also, in schema.sql I need to create the sequences:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BASIS_SEQ START WITH 1000 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE OTHER_SEQ START WITH 1000 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

(if you run this script many times during unit testing, remember to add `drop sequence BASIS_SEQ if exists;` to top of schema.sql)

Comment: Luwil: You know you can add an answer to your own question, if you want to share the solution you applied to your question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Latest HSQLDB provides extensive Oracle syntax compatibility. All you need is add `sql.syntax_ora=true` to your database URL. For example:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_ora=true
```

See the Guide

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html

SQL syntax compatibility is constantly extended in new versions of HSQLDB, so it's best to use the latest available version.

Comment: Thank you @fredt, works like a charm. For others using Spring, I will add text to my question detailing how I changed my configuration (hard to get the formatting right in a comment).

Answer (score 2):

You can still use your original 4 line configuration using `<jdbc:embedded-database ...>`. Just add following line at the beginning of your test-data/schema.sql file:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;
```

This is effectivelly same as appending `sql.syntax_ora=true` to your JDBC URL.